# Can VBA listbox display two values?

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

I have a combobox working as listbox in my userform. Combobox is set to display 2 columns value but when one of the listbox values is chosen only value from column 1 is shown.

Is it possible to show two values - just as 2 columns values work in listbox?

Question asked due to my work with initialization of userform. When it's initialized it should show specific data, but if it's gonna show me only 1 column value most of the time it's useless.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

zmienna = Klient_kraj.Controls("klient").ListIndex

us.ColumnCount = 2
us.List = Range("us").Value

If Not Klient_kraj.Controls("klient").Value = "" Then
    nip.Value = Range("klienci").Cells(1 + zmienna, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value

    'problem starts here
    us.Value = Range("klienci").Cells(1 + zmienna, 1).Offset(0, 3).Value 
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: *`I have a combobox working as listbox`* bad approach :p I don't think you can have 2 columns shown unless you fake it with white spaces and `|` but please do not do that :P What about adding a label to kind of fake the 2nd column and once you get 2 then hide the label? I don't know what I am talking about here ;)

Comment: @mehow I know what you mean, there are always workarounds. I am wondering is it even possible. And one more... what is wrong with using combobox as listbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the column count of the combo box to 2. I don't really see what the problem is.

Edit:

Here is a possible workaround. Make the combobox wide enought to display the necessary values in the two columns. Place a label control over the combobox in the position that the second column would be, but make sure that the right hand side of the label control does not overlap the drop down arrow of the combo box. Set the background style property of the label to transparent. Place the following code in the combo box's change event:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Me.Label1.Caption = Me.ComboBox1.List(Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: This will display 2 columns in the drop down, but once the appropriate line is selected, there will only be 1 value shown in the combo box

Comment: I see. Now I understand your question.

Comment: So... still waiting if it is possible without workarounds like mehow wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround but **without** the need of a `Label`:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    With Me.ComboBox1
        'The if is there to control the unwanted trigger of this code
        If .Value <> "" And InStr(.Value, vbTab) = 0 Then
            .Value = .Value & vbTab & .Column(1)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed Combobox1 to `us` - name of my combobox - error on line: `.Value = .Value & vbTab & .Column(1)` says: Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value.

Comment: @lowak; so, all you did is to change `Private Sub us_Change()` and `With Me.us` and paste the code into your userform's coding module and it pops this error?  Do you see any values in your combobox when you click to dropdown the list?

Comment: Yes, I did change everything according to my code and error pops up. When I click dropdown list I see list of all the data from given range. Other line sets value depending on what was chosen in different combobox: `us.Value = Range("klienci").Cells(1 + zmienna, 1).Offset(0, 3).Value`

Comment: @lowak; I think you will have to tweak the `if` statement from the code I posted so it suits you.  The error probably pops up because when you modify the `.Value` of the combobox it triggers the `ComboBox1_Change()` event.  Also, I have read that `Application.EnableEvents` does not apply to controls (like comboboxes) so you will have to stick with the `if`.

Comment: Well I think problem lies somewhere else... your code should show value from 1st & 2nd column. It's probably very good solution, however it may not suit my list of values. Combobox let me choose values from list with 2 columns, however shows only 1 value. Since it's closed list it may not show anything out of the list - like your code. So... the only think I can think of is probably this fake label posted by mehow and Excel Developers.